# Is there a theoritical explanation/quantification for deeper CNN layers learning more sophisticated features?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have seen the claim that deeper layers in CNN learn to recognize more sophisticated features. This usually comes with a picture of earlier filters recognizing lines/simple curves, and latter filters recognizing more complicated patterns. It makes intuitive sense: the further you are from the data, the more abstract your understanding of it. Is there a theoritical explanation for this, though?

Answer (score 0):

One approach, which is quite close to the intuitive one, would be to look at the receptive field of each layer:

The if the first Convolutional Layer has a kernel size of 3x3, you have a receptive field of size 9, expressed in one (scalar) value in the feature map.

If your second Convolutional Layer now also has a kernel size of 3x3, you have again a receptive field of size 9. But what is in the receptive field now? It's the 9 values of the feature map from the previous layer. Now each of these values has a receptive field of 9 values from the Input Layer, as said before.

If you now look back from the feature map of the 2nd Conv-Layer to the Input Layer, you will have a wider receptive field compared to looking from the feature map of the 1st Conv-Layer to the Input Layer.

So in the 2nd feature map, you will automatically consider more abstract features, since your receptive field in the Input Layer is larger. You can see this quite well in the graphic below, just think of "Map 1" as Input Layer, "Map 2" as Feature Map of the first Conv-Layer, and "Map 3" as Feature Map of the second Conv-Layer.

[image]

You will find more details on the receptive field in the [CS231-course](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/) on CNNs:

Comment: Did this post answer your question? If so, please accept the answer :)